# file_get_contents not working but file exists in browser

Tags: php

Below is my code which does not seem to be working.

```
$addy = "http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29";
$price = json_decode(file_get_contents($addy));
```

`$price` remains `NULL` and i get the following error

> Warning: file_get_contents(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 429 Unknown in...

However, if you go to the web address in your browser the file certainly exists http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29

I don't believe its an issue with security as I've tried it also with CURL. Does PHP treat links different to how the browser does?

Comment: please check data with print_r($price); below last line.

Comment: It showing the proper output: stdClass Object ( [success] => 1 [lowest_price] => $0.21 [volume] => 1,422 [median_price] => $0.21 )

Are you still getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please below code.

```
$addy = "https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=1&appid=730&market_hash_name=Tec-9%20%7C%20Isaac%20%28Field-Tested%29";
$pricefiledata = file_get_contents($addy);
$price = json_decode($pricefiledata);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($price);
echo "<br />";
echo "<br />Price --->".$price->lowest_price;
```

Output display like below.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [success] => 1
    [lowest_price] => $0.21
    [volume] => 1,422
    [median_price] => $0.21
)
Price --->$0.21
```

Comment: All i get with this is

Price --->

Comment: @Andrew what did you get in print_r(); ?

Comment: @Andrew In which server you try this code in local or in live server ?

Comment: this is currently online - live. there was nothing shown apart from what i pasted above. i.e. $price is empty

Comment: @Andrew You mean that you get blank array i.e print_r($price); blank right ? If yes then please try to replace this line. $addy line from my ans.

Comment: i have and it didnt work. If its working for you and in my browser then it must be an issue with my host..

Comment: @Andrew yes its working fine for me. can you please try it in local server or another server.

Answer (score 0):

The error response was 429 from the server. This is a serverside error which prevents scripts like the one i was trying to develop (esentailly i had tried to request to much, to often). This is why the script works locally.